# Stability of eigenvectors for diagonal perturbations

Tags: eigenvalues, eigenvector, stability

In a [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207452/eigenvectors-as-continuous-functions-of-matrix-diagonal-perturbations) I asked about the stability of eigenvalues with respect to diagonal perturbations. Following results from the book  Matrix Analysis (by Roger A. Horn & Charles R. Johnson) the results are quite nice for symmetric matrices. However, they explicitly say that this is not the case for eigenvectors and they give the counter example $\begin{pmatrix} 1& \varepsilon \\ \varepsilon & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

In what I have in mind, only diagonal perturbations are involved, so the counterexample given above is not relevant. I have the following question:

> Suppose $A$ is a real, symmetric, positive-definite matrix and $D$ be a diagonal matrix of the same size. Let $\lambda_1$ be the smallest eigenvalue of $A$ and assume that it is simple.

1. Is there a simple counter example to the stability of eigenvectors in this case? (The eigenvectors corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue of $A+tD$ do not converge towards the eigenvectors of $A$, associated to $\lambda_1$ as $t\to 0$.)
2. If there is no counterexample, do you have a reference for such a stability result?

Comment: It seems this is answered in your link, specifically the quote from Lax's book, Theorem 8, pg 130. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: The general topic of continuous dependence of eigenvectors on the matrix is discussed in this previous question: [MO116123](https://mathoverflow.net/q/116123). One of the answers is again by Peter Michor, but with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple eigenvalues depend smoothly on the matrix by the implicit function theorem
applied to the characteristic polynomial (parameterized by the symmetric matrix).
For the general situation see [this paper](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/DC-perturb.pdf) and references therein.